# Erlang error: payload connection down {shutdown,ssl_closed}

Tags: ssl, erlang

I have some code written in Erlang that consumes from a topic, but after about 8-10 min, I get the error

```
payload connection down reason:{shutdown,ssl_closed}
```

I'm consuming other topics under the same bootstrap server and none of them shuts down, it's only this topic.

I initially tried adding this line in the config first:

```
{reconnect_cool_down_seconds, 10}
```

and then

```
{extra_sock_opts, [{keepalive, true}]}
```

But both didn't resolve the issue.

Would someone have an idea what could be the issue? Let me know if you need more information.

This is the config I have, brod version is 3.15.0.

```
Config = [ 
    {ssl, true}, 
    {reconnect_cool_down_seconds, 10}, 
    %%{extra_sock_opts, [{keepalive, true}]}, 
    {sasl, {scram_sha_512, get_user(), get_password()}} 
] 
ok = brod:start_client(Bootstrap_endpoints, Client_id, Config)
```

Comment: Please use the formatting help when asking and properly insert the code as described there. It is quite easy.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I just noticed the code block!